# Add status code 410 for missing images in Drupal 6

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-6, http-status-code-410

I need to send status 410 for missing images instead of 404, in Drupal 6.
For example I have a image link as `https://www.example.com/our-locations/directory/sub-directory/files/xyz.png` which no longer exist in this location, then I need to send status 410 instead of 404.

Solutions already I have tried are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^our-locations/directory/sub-directory/files/(\.jpg|\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,R=410,L]
```

Comment: REQUEST_URI string always starts with a leading slash. Change your pattern to this `^/our-locations/
directory/sub -directory/files/(\.jpg|\.png)$`

Comment: Thank you @starkreen for your reply. I tried this as well, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: use hook_boot and test if file_exist , if not exit with header 410

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/.+\.(jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
```

The first condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` checks if the the file doesn't exist. Since you want to redirect only 404 images to `410` this condition prevents your other existing files from being redirected to 410. The next condition 
   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/.+\.(jpg|png|gif)$` checks if the uri is `/path/image.ext` if both conditions are met then the `RewriteRule` is applied.

You can also use `<filesMatch>` and `ErrorDocument` directives to catch a 404 image file and then redirect it to a specific page but this will not return the  correct error status. You can use `RewriteRule` instead .

```
<filesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif)$">

ErrorDocument 404 http://exmaple.com/410.php

</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you @starkeen, I tried your this solution. It is working fine if I using it in general (Normal PHP website without any CMS). But when we are trying to implement it in the Drupal 6, it is not working for us. We are using Drupal 6.20 with PHP v5.4.24. Please let me know if it is having any issue with the CMS .htaccess i.e.,
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @TechValens Put this at the top of your `drupal/htaccess` .